# Why is there difference between the matrix after loading a .mat file from Lua torch and pytorch using scipy?

Tags: lua, scipy, pytorch, torch, mat

I have the output matrix from a .mat file using Lua torch 7 and pytorch with scipy both. I am getting the single bit different matrix in using pytorch . Please some one explain me why ? In pytorch matric is in float point, but in Lua torch it has fixe point. How do I fix the point in pytorch.

Here is the matrix.

From Scipy and pytorch Result:

```
tensor([[[112.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
     [ -1.,  -1., 130., 138.,  -1.,  -1.]],

    [[ 57.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
     [ -1.,  -1.,  11.,  53.,  -1.,  -1.]],

    [[ 58.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
     [ -1.,  -1.,  31.,  28.,  -1.,  -1.]],

    [[ 46.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
     [ -1.,  -1.,  24.,  28.,  -1.,  -1.]]])
```

From Lua torch7 result

```
[[[113   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1]
   [-1   -1  131  139   -1   -1]],
   [[57   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1],
   [-1   -1   11   53   -1   -1]],
   [[58   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1],
   [-1   -1   31   29   -1   -1]],
   [[47   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1],
   -[1   -1   24   28   -1   -1]]]
```

you can see the first  element `112` in pytorch but `113` in lua torch. sSimilary `130 & 131` , `138 & 139` , `28 & 29` and `46 and 47`. I want the result similar to Lua torch which is the second matrix. Is there any method to get the fix point in pytorch also.  Please help me out. Thanks